# Searching in pdf file

Tags: pdf, viewers, adobe, search

I'm not 100% sure whether this is a question for this site, but as the base of the code it tex I'll post it here.

I have a simple file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Test for searching \textbackslash{}untilmore

Test for searching \textbackslash{}until

Test for searching \textbackslash{}unti

\end{document}
```

When I create a pdf from this with pdflatex and sear in the pdf file for:

- `\unti` I get 3 matches
- `\until` I get **NO** matches

Used latex version: This is pdfTeX,Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12)

Used reader: Adobe acrobatReader DC Version 2020.013.20074

The resulting image of the pdf file:

[image]

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: Which PDF viewer do you use to search in the PDF? I tried with SumatraPDF (v3.1.2 on Win10) and got three hits for `\unti` and two for `\until`.

Comment: I'm using Adobe acrobatReader DC Version 2020.013.20074 (added this to the question now as well)

Comment: Using sumatra I get 2 matches for `\until`. The same with chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF has (for the first line)

- string `T`
- relative move
- string `est`
- relative move
- string `for`
- relative move
- string `searc`
- relative move
- string `hing`
- relative move
- string `\un`
- relative move
- string `tilmore`

Where the relative moves come from TeX inter word spaces and inter-letter kerns.

So whether a PDF reader finds `\until`  depends on the heuristics of that reader determining what constitutes a word.

In xpdf `\unti` is found three times and `\until` is found twice.

Comment: Sorry I don't get this. I also tried a small file where I removed everything except once `\until` but still nothing found (in acroreader).

Comment: @albert tex adds a kern (small negative space) between n and t in the font you are using, so the string `\until` is not in the PDF but rather the two strings `\un` and `til` this is essentially identical to the PDF you would get from input of two words except words have a larger positive space and inter-letter kerns have a smaller (and in this case negative) space. But there is no definite rule here, the pdf reader has to _guess_ which spaces to ignore when searching.

Comment: I understand that acroreader might see 2 words `un` and `til` but it is a bit strange that searching for `until` so without the `\` does succeed as well as `\unti`. Might of course be some weird (?) heuristic.

Comment: @albert yes seems to be acroread specific perhaps seeing the `\ ` it decided not to ignore small spaces looking for natural language words and uses some "literal code" heuristic instead. I really can't guess what it is doing.

Comment: I get three hits for unti, and two for until in adobe reader.

Comment: Using advanced search in acrobat I get two hits for `\ until`. ( A space between the  \ and the u)

Comment: @SimonDispa interesting observation, I also can find with `\ until` the items. Quite unnatural though.